# Automatically exclude deleted .h/.cpp files from Visual Studio 2017 project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I git cherry-picked huge commit, which removes 400+ files from Visual C++ project folder.

Of course i am getting now 400+ errors like:

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open source file: 'xxx.cpp': No such file or directory
```

No way i am able to exclude each file manually from the project - it will take so much time! Any tools or tricks to help me?

Comment: Were you not able to cherry pick from the change(s) to the `.vcxproj`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vcxproj file is a text file.  Write a sed/perl/python/powershell script that will look for each .cpp file and add the attribute to exclude the .cpp file.

Close the project, run the script, reopen the project - job done.

If you want to entirely remove the .cpp from the project then you will need a bit more care.  However the trick with these things, is that you don't need a general purpose XML parser - you just need enough of a script that will cope with exactly *your* .vcxproj file.